# Does firestore save the change history on the documents?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I had an issue, where I accidentally deleted some data saved on a property of a document of FireStore, and I'm trying to get back the data.

If FireStore saves the change history, it would be easy to retrieve the data, but I don't see if they do.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firestore does not store any sort of change history, you can create this behavior yourself using [Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions) with an [Update trigger](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events)

The only downside is that Cloud Functions does require a Billing account attached and the project upgraded to Blaze Plan.

if that is not an option for you, you will have to create new documents for each revision made to the previous document and update the relative paths to the latest document